# Dynamically write chinese characters into text file using kotlin

Tags: kotlin, encoding, output, text-files

[screenshot of current text file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMYNt.png)

[screenshot of Expected text file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYrZ6.png)

Right now ive issue when writing transactionDescription into text file. So the issue is
although both "Buyers cash1" and "今天去雜貨店購物100元" contains 12 characters
but when written onto the text file the chinese description takes more spaces then just the english
description.1 chinese characters is 2 bytes so now I want to modify the code to make it such
if there's 12 chinese characters it should only add 1 extra space onto the text file before the next details
although the description length is 25 (because the chinese character takes up 12*2)

```
 <beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 http://www.beanio.org/2012/03/mapping.xsd">
<stream name="posting" format="fixedlength">
        <record name="PostingBean" class="cc.process.posting.bean.PostingBean"
                    occurs="0+">
                <field name="BeanDetail" length="1"/>
                <field name="record" length="9"/>
                <field name="idN" length="4"/>
                <field name="Type" length="3"/>
                <field name="uniKey" length="19"/>
                <field name="Code" length="4"/>
                <field name="transactionDescription" length="25"/>
                <field name="Amount" length="11"/>
                <field name="filler" length="73" ignore="true"/>
                <field name="endInd" length="1" literal="|" ignore="true"/>
            </record>
        </stream>
    </beanio>

override fun generatePostingOutputFile(
        postingHeader: PostingHeader,
        postingBeanList: List<PostingBean>,
        postingTrailer: PostingTrailer,
        paramDate: String
    ) {
        val factory = StreamFactory.newInstance()
        try {
            
    factory.load(PostingServiceImpl::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/models/PostingDataGenerationByTc.xml"))
            var path = postingOutputFileDirectory + postingOutputFileName + "_" + paramDate + postingOutputFileExtension
            if (path.startsWith("classpath:")) {
                val url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("")
                path = url.path + path.substring("classpath:".length)
            }
            val maxDescriptionLength = postingBeanList.map { it.transactionDescription?.length ?: 0 }.maxOrNull() ?: 0

            postingBeanList.forEach { postingBean ->
                val originalDescription = postingBean.transactionDescription ?: ""
                if (originalDescription.length < maxDescriptionLength) {
                    postingBean.transactionDescription = StringUtils.rightPad(originalDescription, maxDescriptionLength)
                } else if (originalDescription.length > maxDescriptionLength) {
                    postingBean.transactionDescription = originalDescription.substring(0, maxDescriptionLength)
                }
            }
            val file = File(path)
            Files.createParentDirs(file)
            val encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            val writer = OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, encoding)
            val out = factory.createWriter("posting", writer)
            out.write(postingHeader)
            postingBeanList.forEach(out::write)
            out.write(postingTrailer)
            out.flush()
            out.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            log.error("Printing stack trace: ", e)
            log.info(e.message)
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
class PostingBean
        (tcPostingDataView: TcPostingDataView, index: Int) : Serializable {
        var BeanDetail: String? = Common.DETAIL
        var record: String? = StringUtils.leftPad("" + index + 1, 9, "0")
        var idN: String? = null
        var Type: String? = null
        var uniKey: String? = null
        var Code: String? = null
        var transactionDescription: String? = null
        var Amount: String? = null
        var filler: String? = null
    
        init {
            idN= tcPostingDataView.idN
            Type = tcPostingDataView.Type
            uniKey = tcPostingDataView.uniKey
            Code = tcPostingDataView.Code
            transactionDescription = toFullWidth(tcPostingDataView.transactionDescription)
            Amount =
                StringUtils.repeat("0", 11 - tcPostingDataView.amount?.movePointRight(2).toString().length) +
                        tcPostingDataView.amount?.movePointRight(2).toString()
        }
    fun convertToFullWidth(input: String): String {
        val inputChars = input.toCharArray()
        val outputChars = CharArray(inputChars.size)

        for (i in inputChars.indices) {
            val char = inputChars[i]
            if (char in '0'..'9' || char in 'A'..'Z' || char in 'a'..'z') {
                val index = char.toInt() - ('0'.toInt() - 0xFF10)
                outputChars[i] = index.toChar()
            } else {
                outputChars[i] = char
            }
        }
        return String(outputChars)
    }
}
```

Comment: You just want the columns to align, right? How about changing all the text to full width instead, instead of figuring out how many fewer spaces you need? Depending on the font, you might need fewer or more spaces than you need.

Comment: @Sweeper I tried converting to full width but its still adding the extra spaces. For references : https://pasteboard.co/bDWLQbwqdh0L.png

Comment: At least `今天去雜貨店購物１００元` and `Ｂｕｙｅｒｓ　ｃａｓｈ１` aligned right? You should also use full-width spaces for the right padding to align the rest.

Comment: @Sweeper the description are still not aligned. I only convert the english characters and numbers to full width in order to match the chinese characters but its almost the same as 2 chinese character is the same as 3 full width english character. here's the current output : https://pasteboard.co/NujM5r7OREBB.png

Comment: It's probably something to do with your text editor then. I can see that it is aligned in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @Sweeper okay my bad for the confusion, yes according to your suggestion the normal chinese character and the full width characters are aligned. but i just want the total length to be same not align in the text file for instance a text with 9 chinese characters + 3 number + extra spaces should have the total length of 16 only because that 16 will allign with 25 characters of normal characters. i want attached screenshot on how i expect the text files to look like.
current : https://pasteboard.co/LSRhhCKEVce2.png
expected : https://pasteboard.co/PHK5COZIpksl.png

Comment: How do you know "16 will allign with 25 characters of normal characters"? What would align with 26 characters, or 27 characters? What's the relationship here?

Comment: @Sweeper the max length is 25 so if i add 12 english characters when i output to the file extra 13 spaces will be added to make it 25. but if i have 12 chinese character i want it to only add 1 extra space because 1 chinese character = 2 english character so 12 would techinically be 24 character so by adding 1 space it will be 25. the 16 is because there is 9 chinese character as i mentioned its double so 16+(extra 9 chinese characters) = 25 which will then be equal